# How to catch 404 and 500 error in Rails?

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I am using parse-ruby-client in a Rails web app. According to the documentation at http://www.rubydoc.info/github/adelevie/parse-ruby-client/file/README.md#Logging_In, I can do

```
user = Parse::User.authenticate("cooldude6", "p_n7!-e8")
```

to log a user in. This works as long as the credentials are correct. If they're not correct, I get an error in the Rails app pointing to that line above.

In the logs, I see:

```
I, [2015-10-29T18:41:06.636916 #563]  INFO -- Status: 404
Completed 500 Internal Server Error in 625ms
```

My question is: how do I catch this 404 status and 500 internal server error so the page doesn't get rendered and throw this error? Ideally I'd want to redirect back to the sign in page if there is an error.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to rescue Parse::ParseProtocolError

```
user = Parse::User.authenticate(params[:username], params[:password])
  # continue normally
rescue Parse::ParseProtocolError => e
  status_code = e.code
  # handle error and try again
```

Comment: Thanks! This is working. But do you know how to return the error code that I receive from Parse? That way I can provide the right message to the user. http://parse.com/docs/dotnet/api/html/T_Parse_ParseException_ErrorCode.htm

Comment: I've update the answer, but you should probably have a look at the [source](https://github.com/adelevie/parse-ruby-client/blob/master/lib/parse/error.rb)