# How to catch a 500 Internal Server Error in Rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, api

I have done this tons of times before when fetching things from a database, etc.

For my specific case I am using [a 3rd party](https://github.com/vigetlabs/ruby_spark/blob/master/lib/ruby_spark/device.rb) to connect to a piece of hardware... Anyways, in the case of an error, such as an **invalid id** obviously, we want to raise a exception or a rescue... but unfortunately I don't know how to raise it because by the time it is hit, it's too late (I think)

Here...

```
# 
# getting params and saving item above...
# 

if item.save
  device = RubySpark::Device.new("FAKEUNITID800")
  device.function("req", "ITEM")
  redirect_to controller: 'items', action: 'edit_items'
end
```

If this was a valid ID, everything would work, and it would take you to the `/edit` page! But the issue is, with an invalid ID, it just does...

```
Completed 500 Internal Server Error in 897ms

RubySpark::Device::ApiError - Permission Denied: Invalid Device ID:
```

I checked out the following tutorials

- [Rescue StandardError, Not Exception](https://robots.thoughtbot.com/rescue-standarderror-not-exception)
- [How to catch 404 and 500 error in Rails?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33427586/how-to-catch-404-and-500-error-in-rails)
- [Dynamic Rails Error Pages](https://mattbrictson.com/dynamic-rails-error-pages)

But honestly, they just make me more confused. Maybe I have the wrong approach to this. I always thought that first you make the request, and then you have a fall back case, depending what status (ie. 200, 500, 404) you get... you go from there.

Comment: Can't you just wrap the `RubySpark::Device` call in a `begin`...`rescue` block and handle the `ApiError` exception?

Answer (score 3):

Rails returns an 500 Internal Server Error response because an exception was raised that it does not no how to handle. You can't rescue "500 Internal Server Error" in Rails because it is not an exception - its the framework bailing from an uncaught exception to avoid data loss or unpredictable behavior.

Fortunatly you don't have to. You can just rescue the `RubySpark` exception:

```
begin
  device = RubySpark::Device.new("FAKEUNITID800")
  device.function("req", "ITEM")
rescue RubySpark::Device::ApiError => e
  logger.error(e.message)
end
```

You can also use [`rescue_from`](http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActiveSupport/Rescuable/ClassMethods.html) in Rails controllers that wraps the entire action in a `before` block:

```
class FooController < ApplicationCotnroller
  rescue_from RubySpark::Device::ApiError, with: :do_something
  # ...
end
```

Comment: You might want to start by reading up on how exceptions work in Ruby though as your question seems quite confused. http://rubylearning.com/satishtalim/ruby_exceptions.html

Comment: Dynamic error pages serve a very different purpose and are more for vanity than handling actual errors.

Comment: Thank you, this is exactly what I am looking for!